# Referencing layer object which was created as result of geoprocessing inside MXD without iterating through TOC?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, layers

I am creating a python tool which must be run in and open MXD in ArcMap (10.2, ArcFM). The MXDs we use have a LOT of layers, and often multiple layers from the same datasource. In the script I need to intersect two layers, and use the resulting layer in a selection by location (so it must be added as a layer when created). After the tool has completed the analysis I would like to remove the extra layers from the editor's TOC so they can continue working unimpeded, but not delete the feature class.

Example of geoprocessing function, where `Main` and `Buff` are layers selected from the MXD as tool inputs. I would like to remove "IntersectingGasMain" from the TOC at the end of the tool:

```
MainBuff_Int = arcpy.Intersect_analysis([Main, Buff], "temp_intersect")
```

So far [what I have found](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156951/remove-layer-from-mxd-document-using-arcpy) is that this can be accomplished by iterating through the layers in the active dataframe, comparing the layer datasource property to the result object output:

```
myOut = MainBuff_Int.getOutput(0) # this equals C:\Workspace\test.gdb\"temp_intersect"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.acriveDataFrame
for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if layer.dataSource == myOut:
        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, layer)
```

While I do realize that adding a wildcard in the list layers line would reduce what I have to cycle through, I'm really looking for how to do this using the result object or referencing the featureclass/layer specifically without having to search through the TOC at all... is this possible?

Additionally I can only use funcionality available at the basic license level as the editors cannot access advanced licenses